# Component connected to the store but react not rerendering view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, store

I have Component that connects to the Redux store, this component can watch all changes in the store but react not rendering new view...

Here My Sources:

**Reducer Action**

```
 case 'SET_ACTION_PROPERTY_VALUE':
        const PROP_NAME = action.payload.name;
        const PROP_VALUE = action.payload.value;
        let currentAction = state.currentAction;
        for(var i=0;i< currentAction.parameters.length;i++) {
            if(currentAction.parameters[i].name === PROP_NAME) {
                currentAction.parameters[i].value = PROP_VALUE;
                break;
            }
        }
        return {
            ...state,
            currentAction
        }
```

**component**

```
 const mapStateToProps = state => {
        return {
            currentAction: state.Actions.currentAction,
        }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Parameters);
```

Comment: is there any error in console?

Comment: In console all clear

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because you are mutating the parameter instead of creating a new one. Try replacing : `currentAction.parameters[i].value = PROP_VALUE;` with :

```
currentAction.parameters[i] = {
  ...currentAction.parameters[i]
  value: PROP_VALUE
}
```